# How to use ASP.NET Chart control for 2D bar chart

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am using the ASP.NET chart control and want to create a 2D bar chart like this example:

[image: Sample 2D bar chart]

My data looks like this:

[image: Sample data]

The Product A, Product B, Product C will be the page name (see my data) and the colored bars will be the device type.  Can anyone show me how I might go about doing this?

Comment: Are you using c#? What kind of database is it coming from? Do you need the data to be in an object? is JSON objects an option?

Comment: Data is coming from a SQL Server stored procedure.  I'm using VB.Net, but C# example is fine.  No, I do not need the data in an object and JSON is not an option.  Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? databind? http://www.dotnetpools.com/Article/ArticleDetiail/?articleId=189&title=Asp.Net--2D-and-3D-Charts-Using-C

Comment: I have tried data binding, but having no luck.  Any ideas on how to do what I described?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have the chart controls in place...including all dll's and libraries. you would need to firstly...:

Add a chart to an ASP.NET Page

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"> 
   <series> 
      <asp:Series Name="Series1"> 
      </asp:Series> 
   </series> 
   <chartareas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"> 
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </chartareas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

You can do this by simply dragging the chart control from the toolbox onto the page.

When visited via a client browser the chart control renders an  and a ChartHttpHandler - handles the request.

Next you need to specify the chart data. Including the X axis and Y axis- X indicates the position of the value - Y value indicates the position of the line or the height of the column.

You will then need to bind the database data to the Chart... using DataBindTable.

```
Using myConnection As New SqlConnection 
   myConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NorthwindConnectionString").ConnectionString 

   Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand 
   myCommand.Connection = myConnection 
   myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT CategoryName, COUNT(*) as ProductCount FROM Products p INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID GROUP BY CategoryName ORDER BY CategoryName" 

   myConnection.Open() 
   Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader() 

   chtCategoriesProductCount.DataBindTable(myReader, "CategoryName")

   myReader.Close() 
   myConnection.Close() 
End Using
```

This will create a new series in the Chart Control so you do not need to specifically define a series in the markup language.

Another way to get the data is through the DataSource Property... as follows. This requires an explicit definition of the series for the Chart. Also you will need to specify whether line or bar chart.

The first part looks like:

```
<asp:Chart ID="chtCategoriesProductCountBarChart" runat="server"> 
   <Titles> 
      <asp:Title Text="Number of Products in Categories"></asp:Title> 
   </Titles> 

   <Series> 
      <asp:Series Name="Categories" ChartType="Line" ChartArea="MainChartArea" BorderWidth="5" Color="Red"></asp:Series> 
   </Series>

   <ChartAreas> 
      <asp:ChartArea Name="MainChartArea"> 
      </asp:ChartArea> 
   </ChartAreas> 
</asp:Chart>
```

code behind binding:

```
chtCategoriesProductCountBarChart.Series("Categories").XValueMember = "CategoryName" 
chtCategoriesProductCountBarChart.Series("Categories").YValueMembers = "ProductCount" 

chtCategoriesProductCountBarChart.DataSource = myReader 
chtCategoriesProductCountBarChart.DataBind()
```

I would assume you know where to put this data, as the chart controller. Good luck...

Oh here's my resource...should have much other help there too.. Cheers

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this didn't help.  I can easily create various column charts, but can't figure out how to display a 2D bar chart like I described in my initial post.  The key thing that I can't figure out is how to bind three pieces of data to the chart where the left side will show the page name, each colored bar will represent the device type and the bar length (X axis) will be the number of requests.